# How to define GlassFish domain port?

Tags: java, glassfish, port

Need to know what port is used by particular domain. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Domain Directory of which you want to know the port. Go to domains/{Your_Domain}/config/domain.xml and open it and look for the following lines

```
<network-listeners>
      <network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
      <network-listener port="8181" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
      <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
    </network-listeners>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check domain.xml in domains/domain_name/config/